# ItemChangeListener of JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, itemlistener

I don't understand this - how to get the first selected item?

```
class ItemChangeListener implements ItemListener{
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
           if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
              Object item = event.getItem();
 ---->        if()
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "AW");
                    //UpdateTableStudent();
                else
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, item);
                    //SearchTableStudent();
              }
        }       
   }
```

What to input there when I select the first item?

I mean the index 0...  because there is no

```
event.getSelectedIndex() == 0
```

Comment: Please clarify your question for me.

Comment: i don't know what to put on if() cause i can't use `event.getSelectedIndex() == 0` anycode can use?

Comment: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog should be wrapped into invokeLater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a

```
jcomboBox.getSelectedItem();
```

or
    `jcomboBox.getSelectedIndex();`

though...